# OpenShift route - Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I have deployed a grpc service running on OpenShift Origin. And this backed by a OpenShift service. And the service is exposed with an OpenShift route. I am trying to make this pod available via a service and route that maps the container port (50051) to outside world on port 8080.

The image that the service is trying to expose has, in its Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 50051
```

The route has the following:

- Service Port: 8080/TCP
- Target Port: 50051

In the DeploymentConfig I specify the port with:

```
ports:
 - containerPort: 50051
   protocol: TCP
```

However, when I try to access the application via the route and port, I get (from Java)

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

And when I try to telnet the service IP:

```
telnet 172.30.197.247 8080
```

I am able to connect.

However, when I try to connect via the route it doesnt work:

```
telnet my.route.com 8080
```

Trying ...
telnet: connect to address : Connection refused

When I use:

```
curl -kv my-svc.myproject.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

I can connect.

So it seems the service is working but the route is not.

I have been going through the troubleshooting guide on https://docs.openshift.org/3.6/admin_guide/sdn_troubleshooting.html#debugging-the-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router setups in OpenShift focus on [HTTP/HTTPS(SNI)/TLS(SNI)](https://docs.openshift.org/3.6/dev_guide/getting_traffic_into_cluster.html#using-a-router). However it appears that you can use an [externalIP](https://docs.openshift.org/3.6/dev_guide/getting_traffic_into_cluster.html#using-externalIP) to expose non-web application ports from the cluster.  Because gRPC is an over the wire protocol, you might need to go this path.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to check :

- Is you route point to your service ? Here is a example :

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Route
  spec:
    host: my.route.com
    to:
      kind: Service
      name: yourservice
      weight: 100
  ```

  > If it's not the case, the route and the service are not connected.
- You can check the router configuration. Connect to your router with `oc rsh` and check if you find your route name in the `/var/lib/haproxy/conf/haproxy.config` (the backend name format should be backend be_http_NAMESPACE_ROUTENAME). The `server` part below the backend part should contains the ip of your pod (you can obtain your pod ip with `oc get pods -o wide` command).

  > If it's not the case, the route is not registered in the router config. You can try to restart the router end recheck the haproxy.config file.
- Can you connect to the pod ip from the router container ?